# How does OpenCV's Kalman filter transition matrix handle time (such as t and t^2) for motion prediction?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, kalman-filter

Using a `Kalman filter` to predict motion in 2D space, we usually create the transition matrix with the following equations:

> x(k+1) = x(k) + vt + (1/2)at^2

or simply

> x(k+1) = x(k) + vt

with x: position, v: velocity, a: (constant) acceleration.

This results in a transition matrix that looks like this (for 2D space):

```
1  0  t  0
0  1  0  t
0  0  1  0
0  0  0  1
```

But the OpenCV examples suggest we use the following matrix when setting up the kalman filter in C++:

```
1  0  1  0
0  1  0  1
0  0  1  0
0  0  0  1
```

How can OpenCV interpret this correctly, knowing that a Kalman filter can be used for any dimension and unit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can. Instead of t, I used dt, where dt is the period of the measurements.